# Understanding details in proof of: Suppose $X,$ compact Hausdorff and $Y$ Hausdorff such that $X \subseteq Y$. Then, $X$ is closed in $Y$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Is there a mistake in the proof given or did I misunderstand what has to be shown?

Prop. Suppose $(X, \tau_{X})$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $(Y, \tau_{Y})$ is a Hausdorff space such that $X \subseteq Y$. Then, $X$ is closed in $Y$.

Proof. Let $(X, \tau_{X})$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $(Y, \tau_{Y})$ be a Hausdorff space such that $X \subseteq Y$.

We want to show that $X$ is closed in $Y$ $\iff$ $X^{\complement} = Y \setminus X$ is open in $Y$ $\iff$ for each $y \in Y \setminus X$ there is an open neighborhood $U_{y}$ of $y$ such that $U_{y} \subseteq X^{\complement}$.

So let $y \in X^{\complement} = Y \setminus X$ be arbitrary. Then, $y \in Y$ and $y \notin X$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, for any $x \in X$ (note that $y \neq x$ since $y \notin X$) there is an open neighborhood $U_{x}$ of $x$ and there is an open neighborhood $U_{y}$ of $y$ such that

$$U_{x} \cap U_{y} = \emptyset.$$

Our goal is to show that $U_{y} \subseteq X^{\complement} = Y \setminus X$ i.e. each $y \in U_{y}$ implies $y \in Y$ and $y \notin X$.

But each $x$ has such an open neighborhood $U_{x}$ i.e. $\{ U_{x} \}$ is an open cover of $X$. By compactness of $X$ there is a finite subcover of $\{ U_{x} \}$ which covers $X$.

This is where I was stuck and looked at the book. The book then proceeds by saying

Take $U_{y}$ to be the intersection of all the open neighborhoods of $y$. Then, $U_{y}$ is an open neighborhood of $y$ which does not intersect the finite open subcover $\{ U_{x}^{\iota} \}_{\iota = 1}^{n}$. And hence $y \notin \bar{X}$. It follows that $X$ is closed in $Y$.

Shouldn't this be: And hence $y \notin X$? Or how is the closure $\bar{X}$ of $X$ involved in the proof?

Comment: They found a neighborhood of $y$ that is completely contained in $X^C$. Therefore, $y\notin \overline{X}$.

Comment: So they showed that $y$ is not a contact/adherent/closure point of $X$? And how does $y \notin \bar{X}$ imply that therefore $X$ is closed in $Y$?

Comment: $y$ was arbitrary in $X^C$. So, all points of $X^C$ are in its interior. Hence $X^C$ is open.

Comment: That is odd if that is their argument because the book is Kolmogorov and Fomin Introductory Real Analysis and they have not introduced interior points in the topological setting only in the metric space chapter.

Comment: You could say the conclusion in many ways. The crucial part is the use of Hausdorff to get the covering of $X$ and to use compactness to be able to intersect only finitely many neighborhoods of $y$ to get a new one that is completely inside $X^C$. What is their definition of open? The argument has shown that $X^C$ is a union of open sets.

Comment: The definition of open sets is any set in the topology or equivalently a problem stated that a set $U \subseteq X$ is open if and only if for each $x \in U$ there is an open neighborhood $U_{x}$ of $x$ such that $U_{x} \subseteq U$.

Comment: But the definition of topology includes that arbitrary unions of open sets is open. So, if $X^C$ is the union of all the constructed neighborhoods that don't intersect $X$ of all its points $y$, then it is in the topology.

Comment: Bye the way I just noticed that that is the definition of an interior point am I right?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You should not write $U_y,$ as it depends on $x. $ Call it something else, e.g. $V_x.$ Or perhaps $V_{y,x}$ as a reminder that it is a nbhd of $y$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet How does it depend on $x$? For each $y \neq x \in Y$ there is an open neighborhood $U_{y}$ of $y$. Then, we take the final $U_{y}$ to be the intersection of all the individual $U_{y}$ (ok perhaps here I should have written $U = \cup U_{y}$). But how does it depend on the $x$ other than $y \neq x$?

Comment: So let $y\in X^c.$ For each $x\in X$ there are disjoint nbhds of $x,y.$ So we "fix" $y\in X^c ,$ after which, for each $x\in X$ we select a pair of nbhds.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet ah yes now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is correct. It uses that for any $A \subseteq X$,

$$\overline{A}=\{x \in X: \forall U \text{ open in } X : x \in U \to U \cap A\neq \emptyset \}$$

i.e. the closure is the set of adherence points. Always $Y \subseteq \overline{Y}$ and the proof shows (the $U_y$ is a witnessing open set for this) that $y \in Y^\complement$ is *not* an adherence point, so $Y^\complement \subseteq \overline{Y}^\complement$ so by contrapositive $\overline{Y} \subseteq Y$ and so $Y=\overline{Y}$ and $Y$ is closed.

Comment: So I believe that I understand the logic behind it now. Correct me if I am wrong. So we want to show that $y \in \bar{X}$ implies $y \in X$. We do this by showing the contrapositive, namely, $y \notin X$ implies $y \notin \bar{X}$. So $y \notin X$ means $y \in X^{\complement}$ (since $X \subseteq Y$). Then, the rest of the proof I understand and it shows that $y \notin \bar{X}$. Am I right?

Comment: @sloupo yes, that’s the idea.